# How can i display the 5 latests results from the database at the bottom of the page in PHP instead of displaying it at the top?

Tags: php, sql

This is my PHP file:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `general_chat` ORDER BY `general_chat`.`id` DESC limit 5";


$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<p>";
    echo "<span class = 'usr'>".$row['user_name']."</span>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['message'];
    echo "<br>";
    if($row['Date'] === date("Y-m-d")){
      echo "Today ";
    }
    else{
      echo $row['Date'];
    }

    echo $row['Time'];
    echo "</p>";

  }


}
else{
  echo "No messages were found!";
}


?>
```

This is how my database table looks:
[An image of the database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OiLN.png)

And this is how it displays the data in the PHP file:

[An image of the PHP file output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFjGY.png)

It displays the five latest rows at the top, is it possible to flip and make it display it at the first bottom and then display the others on top of it?

I tried using **DESC** instead of **ASC** but then it displays the five oldest rows instead of the latest

Comment: Don't output immediately... assemble a string with the html and output it at the ende.

Comment: I'm not following, do u mind explainning?

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the initial post. Collect the data from the sql in an array, afterwards apply `array_reverse` to flip the sortorder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is a perfect method
but this could solve your problem

```
select * from (SELECT * FROM `general_chat` ORDER BY `general_chat`.`id` DESC limit 5) G ORDER BY G.id ASC;
```

This IS wrapping your SQL with a similar one
so in subquery it will fetch all latest 5 items and in main query it will sort by ASC

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `general_chat` ORDER BY `general_chat`.`id` DESC limit 5) as G ORDER BY `G`.`id` asc";
```